# AJAX redirect after php post return true or no error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have very very little knowledge of javascript but somehow I managed to post form data to a php file.
Now I am facing a little problem, there are some validations on php file, what I want is if there is any validation fails and the php file returns `$error = 'Invalid data';` I want this ajax request to simply display the error message.
Or, if it returns no error, or `$error = '';` this ajax request redirect to thankyou.php page.
HTML file:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'true') {
                    window.location.href="thankyou.php";
                };
                if (data !== 'true') {
                    $("#status").html(data);

                };
            },
            error: function(){
            }           
        });
    }));
});
```

```
<form id="frmContact" action="" method="post">
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span><br/>
        <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="demoInputBox">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btnAction" />
    </div>
</form>
```

data.php

```
<?php

// PHP code above...
//Lets add $error variable for test purpose...

$error = 'Invalid data';

?>
```

Comment: you are checkinh in success for true, but in php, you are echoing `Invalid Data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change only success function like this

```
success: function(data){
            if (data === 'Invalid data') {
                  $("#status").html(data);                    
            }
            else {
                window.location.href="thankyou.php";
            }
        }
```

and in php you should echo `$error`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But I'm getting this error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'else'`

Comment: sorry its my mistake, remove semicolon after if and else, i will edit my answer. you can check that.

Comment: That error is fixed, thanks. But it is redirecting even if I echo Invalid data.

Comment: inside success(), alert(data) before if statement and check what you are getting...

Comment: All good now. Alert showed some other error message from the php file stopping it to work as expected. Just fixed the php file and all done. Thankyou so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Echo out "Success" if everything goes according to what you wanted in the posted data i.e all validations passed or echo out any specific validation error. The echoed response will be the response according to which our JS will act accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false

            })
            .done(function(response){
            if(response=="Success")
                window.location.href="thankyou.php";
            else 
                $("#status").html(response);
            });
        }));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But for some reason, it is not redirecting.
And it does display "Success" in #stats